# Create effect dark and light when game start in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new in unity, i need to create a effect when my game is started:

- When game is being started, game scene is dark
- When game has already been started, game scene is light.

Please teach me how i can do it, Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

1st you have to add Light on your scene from GameObject Menu in unity. If you need On Off that light just add the Javascript to your light. Lot of ways to do this Google it and easy to find.

```
var times : float;
function Start () {
light.intensity =0;
}

function Update () {
times += Time.deltaTime; // just I added time.
if (times > 5) // or Here you can use Press key events....
 light.intensity =8;
}
```

Comment: my game is 2d, i am not sure that Light is not effect in 2D, because I add a Light but light of scene is not changed.

Comment: You'll need to add a material to your sprites for this which uses the Sprites Diffuse shader. As standard, sprites don't support lighting as we expect users to use them unlit and use lighting baked into the sprite design itself. Simply make a material, assign it to the sprite, and choose the Sprites Diffuse shader from the material. Check this links [1](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/2d-lighting.210642/) [2](http://www.theappguruz.com/tutorial/unity-lighting-effect-on-2d-sprite-in-unity/) [3](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GI63eeaXbWs&feature=plcp)

Comment: If It gives Solution then Accept it as Answer . .

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I use. I create a pixel texture and use the GUI system to ensure it'll be drawn before everything in the scene. I actually use a display manager to control the order GUI elements are drawn to make sure the overlay is in front of other gui elements.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Overlay : MonoBehaviour {

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

    [SerializeField]
    private Color                                           screenColor         = Color.black;
    [SerializeField]
    private float                                           fadeSpeed           = 0.5f;

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

    static private Texture2D                        overlay;
    static private bool                                 fadeOverlay;
    static private bool                                 fadeOverlayIn;

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

    public void Awake() {
        //Setup the values for the fading overlay.
        overlay = new Texture2D( 1, 1 );
        overlay.SetPixel( 0, 0, screenColor );
        overlay.Apply();
        fadeOverlay = true;
        fadeOverlayIn = false;
    }

    public void Update() {
        if ( fadeOverlay ) {
            if ( fadeOverlayIn ) {
                screenColor.a += Time.deltaTime * fadeSpeed;
                if ( screenColor.a >= 1 ) {
                    fadeOverlay = false;
                }
            } else {
                screenColor.a -= Time.deltaTime * fadeSpeed;
                if ( screenColor.a <= 0 ) {
                    fadeOverlay = false;
                }
            }
            overlay.SetPixel( 0, 0, screenColor );
            overlay.Apply();
        }
    }

    public void OnGUI() {
        if ( fadeOverlayIn || fadeOverlay ) {
            GUI.DrawTexture( Camera.main.pixelRect, overlay );
        }
    }

    static public void Toggle() {
        fadeOverlay = true;
        fadeOverlayIn = !fadeOverlayIn;
    }

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your share. I am trying this

Comment: Did this help at all?